# Deployed artefact in Artifcatory does not show up in virtual repo

Tags: artifactory, ivy

I have an artefact (`com.test#verifier;1.1`), that I deploy on a repository called `libs-release-local`. This repo has as `Virtual Repository Association`,  amongst others one called `libs-release` (this is from what I understood a default one given by Artifactory).

In my project I have in the `ivy-settings.xml` the following

```
 <resolvers>
<chain name="main">
  <url name="artifactory" m2compatible="false">
    <artifact
      pattern="${ivy.artifactory.server}/${ivy.repo}/${ivy.default.artifact.pattern}" />
    <ivy
      pattern="${ivy.artifactory.server}/${ivy.repo}/${ivy.default.ivy.pattern}" />
  </url>
  <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" 
           root="http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/libs-release" />
</chain>
```

When fetching the artefact, it fails though with

```
[ivy:retrieve]      module not found: com.test#verifier;1.1
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== artifactory: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/unstable/com.test/verifier/1.1/ivys/ivy-1.1.xml    
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact com.test#verifier;1.1!verifier.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/unstable/com.test/verifier/1.1/jars/verifier-1.1.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/libs-release/com/test/verifier/1.1/verifier-1.1.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact com.test#verifier;1.1!verifier.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/libs-release/com/test/verifier/1.1/verifier-1.1.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: com.test#verifier;1.1: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve] 
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

Apparently my assumption is false, when I deploy to `libs-release-local`, it is also accessible via `libs-release`.

What do I need to do, that with the given ivy-settings, I do receive the dependency ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the artifact from libs-release-local? have you tried resolving the artifact from libs-release using curl?

Comment: when I change the the ivy-settings.xml to use `libs-release-local`, so can I successfully resolve the dependency

Comment: Can you trace the request to the virtual repository - http://artifactory:9090/artifactory/libs-release/com/test/verifier/1.1/verifier-1.1.jar?trace

Comment: I uploaded the failing trace to libs-release here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0bc2dladwmcky3/trace.txt?dl=0


And also the successful trace to libs-release-local here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2tyxg15t1hhx7r/trace-found.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided request trace, the issue is with include/exclude patterns configured for the libs-release repository:

```
2017-05-30T09:33:57.915+02:00 Adding no aggregated repositories - requested artifact is rejected by the include exclude patterns of 'libs-release'
```

You should take a look at the libs-release repository configuration and check which pattern(s) is causing the file download to be rejected.